# Nothing append with onAnimationEnd on React

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem using onAnimationEnd on React.
i have an overlay div and i change its class in 4 steps (with setState) :

1. initial step : overlay div class = *displayNone*
2. step 2 : a button with onClick event display the overlay div with class = *fade-in*
3. step 3 : a button in the overlay with onClick event change class to *fade-out*
4. step 4 : an onAnimationEnd event on the overlay div should change class to *displayNone*

But step nothing happen on step 4, the class stay on *fade-out*
What i'm doing wrong ?

Thank you

code is [here](https://codepen.io/gazowski/pen/JjGyaVB):

```
class Buttons extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.buttons = ['Hello Overlay','Goodbye Overlay']
    this.state = {
      overlayClass : 'displayNone',
    }
  }
  
  render(){
    return(

     <div>
        <h1>Overlay fade-in fade-out</h1>
          <button type='button' 
            onClick={() => this.setState({ overlayClass : 'fade-in' })}>{this.buttons[0]}</button>
        <div className={`overlay ${this.state.overlayClass}`}
          onAnimationEnd={() => this.setState({ overlayClass : 'displayNone' })}>
          <button type='button' 
            onClick={() => this.setState({ overlayClass : 'fade-out' })}
             >{this.buttons[1]}</button>
        </div>
      </div>
  )}
  
}
ReactDOM.render(<Buttons />, document.body);
```

Answer (score 2):

So first of all in the codepen you've provided you were using some ancient version of React and ReactDOM - for some reason it was not working correctly with onAnimationEnd event. With the latest version of React it's working properly.

Here's [fixed codepen](https://codepen.io/DM89/pen/LYGjMLQ?editors=0010)

Notice that in handleAnimationEnd method I'm checking for current `overlayClass` to be `fade-out` because onAnimationEnd fires each animation so when you're changing `overlayClass` from `fade-in` to `displayNone` you'll never see the 'Goodbye Overlay' button.